# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object in Unity Proyect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with my game in Unity. The moment I boot it, through the console, I see this message: NullReferenceException: Object Reference Not Set on an Instance of an Object. I don't know what's possible. Since the game is working properly. The only thing that does not show the contents of the variable. I tested with a Debug to the variable and this takes the content. So it's not null.

My code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Managers;
using TMPro;
    
public class StateButtonChipsClub : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject ButtonChipsClub;
    
    public bool isAdmin => TablesManager.Instance.club.isMyClub;
    public int chipsAmount => TablesManager.Instance.club.clubChips;
    
    public void Start()
    {
            
        if (isAdmin != true)
        {
            ButtonChipsClub.SetActive(false);
        } 
        else 
        {
            Debug.Log("CHIPS AMOUNT = "+chipsAmount.ToString());
                
            ButtonChipsClub.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = 
                chipsAmount.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `ButtonChipsClub.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>()` actually return something?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Obviously, your `TablesManager.Instance.club` variable is not being initialized before accessing it's properties. How are you initializing it?

Comment: You should return a text. But it doesn't.

Comment: I thought it was already initialized when I made the call. Since with isAdmin I don't feel like it. And using Manager is refence TablesManager.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem. In the end I declared the variable above.

```
public TextMeshProUGUI text;
```

And then I called it in the else like this:

```
text.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = chipsAmount.ToString();
```